# jquery script seems to wait when php file is called

Tags: php, jquery, event-handling

I am trying to load a div with .load(). When a menu-element is clicked this function is triggered:

```
function newPage(p_id){
    var id = p_id;

    $("#div").load("content.php?id=" + id);

    doSomething();
    doAnotherThing();
}
```

The content.php works fine. But the `doSometing()`; is not happening. The next time I click a menu-element, the `doSomething()`; and the `doAnotherThing()`; are fired and then the function begin from the start and halts again before the `doSomething()`; Of course I intend to execute the function from the beginning till the end on each click.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Does `doSomething()` or `doAnotherThing()` do something? ;p

Comment: Yes, they change the style of elements that have been loaded by the .load() function.

Comment: @Jan so you have to wait loaded content to be added in the DOM if calling methods on them

Comment: Thanks, roasted. Your other answer solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
$("#div").load("content.php?id=" + id,function(){doSomething(); doAnotherThing();});
```